# Asp.net session expiring automatically after few seconds in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, authentication

When user login, I'm storing user_id in Session variable and on second page I'm checking on page load if user_id exists then fine, otherwise redirect to sign in page but when I login and and redirected to next page after few seconds it will redirect on login page. I have tried all solutions but all in vain

**Important Note:** 
Another thing is that application working fine on development server and also on local IIS in LAN but on live server this issue is occurring.
Following web.config file code is

```
 <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <trust level="Full" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Security/Registration" timeout="30" 
         slidingExpiration="true"  />
  </authentication>
  <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 </system.web>
```

Comment: you are using form authentication in mvc? why not try to use identity instead?

Comment: Show us how you set the variable, how you get and compare it and where exactly it fails.

Comment: my best guess is that your cookie/session timer is not set or you have set it for afew seconds.

Comment: I am setting values like this one`Session["User"] = obj.ID;
                            Session["UserName"] = obj.FullName;
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(obj.Email, false);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you update `sessionState` with below line :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />
```

Comment: Nikunj Patel still same error on my local development machine its running good but when problem in live server when i live my project on server its creating problem session value expire after some seconds.I am using shared hosting.

Comment: @BedSpace, As far as everything looks okay. In that case you can ask for the support from hosting provider may be their hosting configuration can causing this issue! They might help you !!

Comment: Yes i asking from hosting team they said to me your website is resource hungry that's way creating problem for me.

Comment: @BedSpace, its a good challenge for you to make it less resource hungry ! You should look at `IDisposable` for managing the `GarbageCollector`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set timeout in web.config

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" />
     ....
```

Comment: still same error on my local development machine its running good but when problem in live server when i live my project on server its creating problem session value expire after some seconds.I am using shared hosting.